# Converting DDMMMYYYY to date format in pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

I have dates in a DataFrame's column like:

```
1    06AUG2010
2    07APR2011
```

I want to convert them to a type, where i can count diffrences between dates in days.
I'm searching the internet for the answer, but cant find it. New to pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with custom [format](http://strftime.org/):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['06AUG2010','07APR2011']}, index=[1,2])
print (df)
        date
1  06AUG2010
2  07APR2011

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y')
print (df)
        date
1 2010-08-06
2 2011-04-07
```

And then for differences add [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
df['date'] = df['date'].diff()
print (df)
      date
1      NaT
2 244 days
```